# Context API state do not changing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, next.js13

AA I am working with context API where everything working fine except the button which takes a value that when clicked it should add the value in the global variable as if I add 10 it will add 1 to any value it adds 1
code for provider

```
`"use client";
import React, {
  useState,
  createContext,
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction,
} from "react";

export const Context = createContext({
  quantity: 0,
  addToCart: (q: number) => {},
  removeFromCart: (q: number) => {},
});

const CartProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);
  const addToCart = (q: number) => {
    setQuantity((prevQuantity) => prevQuantity + 1);
  };
  const removeFromCart = (q: number) => {
    setQuantity((prevQuantity) => prevQuantity - 1);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Context.Provider value={{ quantity, addToCart, removeFromCart }}>
        {children}
      </Context.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default CartProvider;
`
```

counter is working fine at end it has button component and at top as perimeters of counter component it takes show button value and this logic is working fine so here is code for counter

```
    "use client";
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import Button from "./button";
import { Context } from "./QuantityContext";

const Counter = ({
  price,
  product_id,
  showButton = true,
}: {
  price: number;
  product_id: string;
  showButton?: boolean;
}) => {
  const { addToCart, removeFromCart } = useContext(Context);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

  const increment = () => {
    if (showButton === false) {
      addToCart(value + 1);
      setValue(value + 1);
    } else {
      setValue((prevQuantity) => prevQuantity + 1);
    }
  };

  const decrement = () => {
    if (showButton === false) {
      removeFromCart(value - 1);
      setValue(value - 1);
    } else if (value > 1) {
      setValue((prevQuantity) => prevQuantity - 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-10">
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center gap-4">
        <h1 className="font-semibold text-lg">Quantity:</h1>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={decrement}
          className={`w-10 h-10 ${
            value === 1 ? "cursor-not-allowed" : ""
          } bg-gray-200 hover:shadow-lg rounded-full text-3xl font-light`}
          disabled={value === 1}
        >
          -
        </button>

        <div className="flex justify-center items-center text-lg">{value}</div>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={increment}
          className="w-10 h-10 bg-gray-200 rounded-full border-2 border-black hover:shadow-lg text-3xl font-light"
        >
          +
        </button>
      </div>
      {showButton && (
        <div id="button" className="flex gap-4">
          <Button quantity={value} price={price} product_id={product_id} />
          <p className="font-bold text-xl leading-8 tracking-wider">${price}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

and this code is for button

```
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { CgShoppingCart } from "react-icons/cg";
import toast, { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
import { Context } from "./QuantityContext";

const Button = ({
  quantity,
  price,
  product_id,
}: {
  quantity: number;
  price: number;
  product_id: string;
}) => {
  const { addToCart } = useContext(Context);

  console.log(`amount: ${quantity}`);

  const initialButtonClassName =
    "flex bg-[#212121] text-white justify-center items-center px-4 py-2 border-t-2 border-t-[#545454] border-l-2 border-l-[#545454] border-r-2 border-r-black border-b-2 border-b-black";
  const activeButtonClassName =
    "flex bg-[#212121] text-white justify-center items-center px-4 py-2 border-t-2 border-t-black border-l-2 border-l-black border-r-2 border-r-[#545454] border-b-2 border-b-[#545454]";
  const [buttonClassName, setButtonClassName] = useState(
    initialButtonClassName
  );
  const sendData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/cart", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          quantity,
          price,
          product_id,
        }),
      });
      if (response.ok) {
        toast.success("Successfully added product to your cart. Enjoy");
        return await response.json();
      } else {
        toast.error("Sorry something went wrong");
        return await response.json();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("An error occurred while adding product to cart:", error);
    }
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setButtonClassName(activeButtonClassName);
    console.log(quantity);
    addToCart(quantity);
    sendData();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (buttonClassName === activeButtonClassName) {
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        setButtonClassName(initialButtonClassName);
      }, 100);
      return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
  }, [buttonClassName, initialButtonClassName, activeButtonClassName]);

  return (
    <button className={buttonClassName} onClick={handleClick}>
      <Toaster />
      <CgShoppingCart style={{ fontSize: "24px", color: "white" }} />
      Add to Cart
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

Comment: As per my understanding, when you are calling addToCart(quantity), is adding 1 every time even if you are sending 10 as quantity. It is like addToCart(10) is adding 1 to the cart instead of 10 right?

Comment: const addToCart = (q: number) => {
    setQuantity((prevQuantity) => prevQuantity + 1);
  };

In this you are not using the input parameter which is q; Instead, you are only using the prevQuantity. To make it work, you can use the input parameter q like below which would make it work.

  const addToCart = (q: number) => {
    setQuantity((prevQuantity) => prevQuantity + 1 + q); // you can change this as per needs.
  };

Comment: And also the button component should not have any logic related to API calls or using useContext. You can pass the callbackHandlers & data from the Counter component.